# Getting warning in Gatsby JS (react) regarding having a unique key prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I get the following error on a react component. I thought I had set a unique key when I look in graphQL playground explorer the id I am grabbing is unique for each element. So I am not sure why I am getting this error. I read that the elements inside my also need a key which I thought wasn't the case. Hopefully someone can help.

Error

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

GraphQL Query

```
query MyQuery {
  allDatoCmsPricing {
    edges {
      node {
        id //This was orignally there when I posted
        details {
          id //This was missing that was my error which was answered
          task
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

GraphQL Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "allDatoCmsPricing": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "details": [
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1919839-en",
                "task": "Client Consultation"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1919840-en",
                "task": "S.M.A.R.T Goal Setting"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1919841-en",
                "task": "Fitness Assessment"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1919842-en",
                "task": "Client Centered Exercises"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1919843-en",
                "task": "1-2 Sessions per week"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "details": [
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927942-en",
                "task": "Client Consultation"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927943-en",
                "task": "S.M.A.R.T Goal Setting testing breaking line"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927945-en",
                "task": "Fitness Assessment"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927946-en",
                "task": "Client Centered Exercises"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927947-en",
                "task": "Injury Prevention"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927948-en",
                "task": "Nutrition Advice"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927949-en",
                "task": "Program Design"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927950-en",
                "task": "Corrective Exercises"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927951-en",
                "task": "3 or more Sessions per week"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "details": [
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927866-en",
                "task": "Client Consultation"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927867-en",
                "task": "S.M.A.R.T Goal Setting"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927868-en",
                "task": "Fitness Assessment"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927869-en",
                "task": "Client Centered Exercises"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927870-en",
                "task": "Injury Prevention"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927872-en",
                "task": "Nutrition Advice"
              },
              {
                "id": "DatoCmsItem-1927873-en",
                "task": "2-3 Sessions per week"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Component

```
    {data.allDatoCmsPricing.edges.map(({ node: pricing }) => ( 

    <div key={pricing.id} >

    <ul className="details-list">{pricing.details.map(detailEntry => { 
       return <ListItem key={detailEntry.id}><span>{detailEntry.task}</span> 
       </ListItem>      
    })}</ul>

    </div>

    ...
```

Comment: It looks like the problem might be that you have two `map` functions happening. You are assigning a key for the second `map` but the first one you are not assigning a key to the mapped `ul`. Not sure if they are nested though.

Comment: I added some code to explain further what is going on, I removed alot of my code because it's quite large but the ul has a wrapping div with a key id

Comment: and the warning is coming specifically from the line where the ListeItem key is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `pricing.id` is `undefined`. It's represented by `node.id` in your data, but you only have a `details` property present. Your graphql query reflects this. Adding `id` to the query should resolve the error:

```
query MyQuery {
  allDatoCmsPricing {
    edges {
      node {
        id # <--- Added this field
        details {
          id
          task
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: actually I had the opposite I was missing the id under details and had it under node, which was needed. I will update my question, but you solved it for me.